# Why my monitor connected via usb-c hdmi display blue lines?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi

When I connect monitor to my new MacBook Pro 2020 13 inch via hdmi to usb-c then I can see the picture like this:

[image]

Why there is a lot of blue points?

My cable and converter:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a TV.  Disable any picture enhancements in the TV:

Comment: What do you mean? It is just simple monitor from Samsung.

Comment: I'm sure you mean USB-C to HDMI. It looks like the first signs of a dying GPU, but on a new machine I'd first suspect your converter/cable.

Comment: @Tetsujin. One more question: First signs of dying GPU on my additional monitor or on my Macbook Pro? It is possible for my monitor, because it is quite old (5-6 years), and my converter is like in the question, I have added an image and is relatively new. Cable is hdmi -hdmi and is also old.

Comment: Displays don't have GPUs. The converter/cable is still my prime suspect.

Comment: @Tetsujin If there was a problem with GPU, would "blue signs" be also presented on my Macbook Pro?

Comment: I keep saying, now three times, I don't think it's the GPU, I think it's the converter or cable. I've seen the issue present on only one of several monitors - but because the computer is brand new, that is not my first suspect. The cheap adapter is.

Comment: Thank you for your help;) I will replace adapter.

Comment: Is there another monitor you can test it on, even if that means popping next door?